# Can golang read the mpr written by imageMagick?

Tags: go, imagemagick

I need to use the webpage to display the thumbnail of the local image, golang as the server, call imageMagick to generate the thumbnail, can I do it directly in memory?

I only found the mpc parameter but don't know how to use

> mpr：This format permits you to write to and read images from memory. The filename is the registry key. The image persists until you explicity delete it or the program exits.

https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#mpr

---

Thanks for the reply, I already know this can't be done.

@Steffen Ullrich,thanks for the recommendation.

I tried imagick but it wasn't ideal, it took almost 30s to read a 20m image,it only takes less than 2s to use convert.exe.
So I decided to generate the thumbnail first and then read it

Comment: You cannot simply access the memory of a different process. mpr is not the way to go. Use bindings like https://github.com/gographics/imagick instead.

Comment: I find your question difficult to understand. I see there's some Golang somewhere and an image but I have no idea where the image is (server back-end or browser), where the Golang or ImageMagick are, what processing is required nor where the result is supposed to be sent. Maybe you could click [edit] and clarify. Thank you.